# Specific wifi network suddenly stopped working. Why?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

There is nothing wrong with my wifi connection. I have also used the same network before on the same mobile, but suddenly this problem occurs. Whenever I try connect to the Internet through the wifi one message shows that 'Internet is not available on this Wifi ap, change network...'

(Phone is a Samsung Galaxy S Duos 7562)

What to do?

Comment: Are you (or anyone in the area) able to connect with a different device? Have you tried enabling/disabling Airplane mode? Have you tried turning off/on the device? Is it possible that the owner of the wifi access point has changed it? Is it possible that their Internet is down?

Comment: It also occurs sometimes with my Galaxy Y Duos...

Comment: Can you to (from a pc, connected via usb) do `adb logcat -v time` and check the output at that specific time?